# How to create a "no results" message box in a search form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access DB, where I have a "Quick search" form that is a simply text box that opens my "Customer Viewer" form on the record that is searched. Now what I want to add is some sort of an error-handler that prompts a "No result" message box in a case where there is no match to the search(instead of the current situation where it just opens my "Customer Viewer" form with no data.

This is my current code for clicking the search button:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCustomerViewer", acNormal, , "[FirstName]='" & Me.txtSearchBox & "' OR [LastName]='" & Me.txtSearchBox & "'"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DCount` to determine how many rows match your search criteria.  If one or more rows match, open the form.  If no rows match, display a message with `MsgBox`.

```vb
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
    Dim strCriteria As String
    strCriteria = "[FirstName]='" & Me.txtSearchBox & _
        "' OR [LastName]='" & Me.txtSearchBox & "'"
    If DCount("*", "YourTableOrQueryNameHere", strCriteria) > 0 Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCustomerViewer", acNormal, , strCriteria
    Else
        MsgBox "no results"
    End If
End Sub
```

However that approach would break when `Me.txtSearchBox` contains an apostrophe.  You can avoid that risk by replacing each single apostrophe with two ...

```vb
strCriteria = "[FirstName]='" & Replace(Me.txtSearchBox, "'", "''") & _
    "' OR [LastName]='" & Replace(Me.txtSearchBox, "'", "''") & "'"
```